# click event firing but unable to addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following that's not working.  The console.log is getting the div id but I'm not able to add or remove class:

```
function detectDiv(obj) {
 var parent = obj.parentElement;
 console.log(parent.id);


$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(parent.id).removeClass("grey100");
} else {
    $(parent.id).addClass("grey100");
}
}); 


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#"+ parent.id).removeClass("grey100");
} else {
    $("#"+ parent.id).addClass("grey100");
}
});
```

Since u mentioned that u are getting the id in console correctly. Adding "#"(id selector) will work.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a query selector

```
$("#"+parent.id).addClass("grey100");
```

Though you really don't have to, you can just use the parent.

```
$(parent).addClass("grey100");
```